# gnome-terminal cmd leaving processes open after closing parent window

Tags: bash, shell, process, gnome

The following simple command should demonstrate my issue:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "Tab 1" -e "/bin/bash" --tab -t "Tab 2" -e "/bin/bash"
```

This should open a new window with two tabs and an active bash shell.  If I immediately close this new window using the GUI [x] and then execute a ps command, one (in this case) sub process (/bin/bash) will be left open.  I have found out that this corresponds to all inactive tabs that have never been made active (by clicking on them) at some point in time.  So if we crafted a new command similar to the example above but with 5 tabs instead of 2 and you immediately closed this window after running the command, 4 sub-processes will be left running.  Here is the peculiar part...if you click on each tab to make it active and then close the window, all of the sub-processes will be killed, as one would expect.

Is this a bug in gnome-terminal?

How can I ensure these processes are closed and not left open?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com would be better for this

Comment: What state are the subprocesses in? Are they zombies? Either way, this does sound like a bug in gnome-terminal.

Comment: I don't think they are zombies.  I must confess--I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to the ps command and unix in general.  I do not see a 'Z' in the STAT column.  It appears that the parent process ID of the process(es) left open is the PID of the terminal from which the command above is executed.  I would expect that closing the newly spawned window would be enough to kill the sub-processes corresponding to each tab (regardless of whether it has been made active or not), not having to kill the original, source terminal.  Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Run like below:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "Tab 1" -e "bash -ic 'echo Hello; exec bash'" --tab -t "Tab 2" -e "bash -ic 'echo Hello; exec bash'"
```

You need to run some comand before the ;bash and you can change 'echo Hello' by any other.